# How to find file inside openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift, into-outfile

Consider, that I have a rest service that responses the csv-file to the client.
The csv-file is produced by query to mysql:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
String path = (df.format(new Date()))+"-"+limit+".csv";
String fileQuery = String.format("Select * INTO OUTFILE '%s' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' from some_table ", path);

/*Executing query*/

Path p = (Path) Paths.get(path);
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) p.toFile());
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename="+p.getFileName());

return response.build();
```

Both jboss application and mysql are hosted on RH Openshift gears. 
The question is - where i can find the outfile, generated by mysql?

It seems to me, that mysql gear has different environment from jboss so when I create csv file test.csv written by

```
select into outfile '/tmp/test.csv' ...
```

I can not find it in /tmp directory.

I tried to use in path some openshift environment variables, e.g. OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, etc. with the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try sshing into the gear `rhc ssh <mysqlApp>` and to `find -name '<filename>.csv' 2>/dev/null`? If I just ssh into my gear with MySQL and select something into a file, it ends up in `~/mysql/data/<DBname>/`.

Comment: 2Jiri Fiala - thanks for the proposal. When I ssh (simple terminal, not rhc) to application with login provided by OpenShift I can find nothing.

Comment: mysql> use mydatabase
    Database changed
    mysql> select * from Track limit 5 into outfile 'test123.txt';
    Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> exit
    Bye
    [myapplication.rhcloud.com login]\>find / -name 'test123.txt' -print 2>/dev/null
    [myapplication.rhcloud.com login]\>

I suppose that particulary in my configuration the MySQL gear does not share filesystem with Jboss gear

Comment: I'm sorry, I told you to ssh into the primary app gear, instead of the gear where the DB resides. For that, just run `rhc app-show <yourApp> --gears` (which will list gears and their SSH URLs) and then ssh into the gear where the database is located (using `ssh <gearURL>`, not `rhc ssh <appName>`).